# How to remove extra spaces from VS Code Editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I was working on VS Code Editor and suddenly I pressed some key which created this space around window

[image]

How can I remove this space?

Comment: Disable `View/Appearance/Centered Layout` if it is enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to View/Appearance/Centered Layout as shown in the image and disable it:

[image: VS code]